# Can I use partitionn of HDD for playing Xbox 360 games

Tags: xbox-360

I am planning to buy an xbox 360 console. my budget permits me acess to only the 4 GB one which needs extra space for many games' install. I have an external HDD of size 40GB. My question is can I divide it into partitions such thet I can use one for gaming on xbox and the other for data storage.

Comment: This is a great question that I hope to see answered.

Comment: Look here: a new question was asked and answered with the same topic : http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261359/can-i-partition-a-hdd-for-playing-xbox-360-games

Comment: Those two questions have literally the same text. Same user? Copy and paste?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean other data storage for a PC or for other data on the Xbox?

If you mean other data for the Xbox then you should have no problem using it. Just format the hard drive for the 360 to read and you're ready to go.

If you what to use the other data for a PC, I'd have to say you probably can not. When you go to format a hard drive for an Xbox 360, it formats the whole drive.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this, but I seem to remember issues if the drive is not a Scorpio drive or something along those lines.

You can use a decent USB stick for this, or I would suggest buying a proper Xbox drive off ebay.

See here the steps to use your own drive for xbox. I *was* tempted but in the end I just couldn't be bothered. http://www.instructables.com/id/Upgrading-the-Xbox-360-hard-drive-CHEAP/